# max over time for CPU usage node_cpu_seconds_total in prometheus

Tags: windows, prometheus, cpu, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to get metric for my CPU utilization like max over time, something like below:-

```
max (max_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:rate5m[30d])) by (pod_name)
```

I tried to make the query using with idle where i want result in a day and max over 15mins duration:-

```
max_over_time(sum by (Name,job,mode) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=~"WEBRTC(.*)-server-nodes",mode="idle"}[10m]))[1d:15m])
```

But when I am doing !=idle, am getting wrong results.

Thanks.

Comment: How two of the queries related? And what constitutes "wrong results"?